# how to bind mx4j to an ipaddress rather than localhost in jetty?

Tags: mx4j

I am using mx4j in jetty to have a web console to my jmx bean. However, mx4j by default only bind to localhost. I don't know how to set to by to the ipaddres of my machine rather than localhost. Here is my code:

```
MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
MBeanContainer mBeanContainer=new MBeanContainer(mbeanServer);      
mBeanContainer.setManagementPort(1500);     
mBeanContainer.start();     
server.getContainer().addEventListener(mBeanContainer);  
// server is Jetty Server
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. YOu need to setup HttpAdapter with XSTL translator like this

```
HttpAdaptor adapter = new HttpAdaptor();
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Server:name=HttpAdaptor");
mbeanServer.registerMBean(adapter, name);
adapter.setPort(1500);
adapter.setHost("MyIpAddress");
adapter.setProcessor(new XSLTProcessor());
adapter.start();
```